# How can I disable build manager role in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cm-synergy

How can I disable build manager role. I just want to extract the code from synergy to my workspace. Will be of great help..

```
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\Synergy\7.1\bin\ccm.exe" set role build_mgr ccm command failed Warning: 'build_mgr' is not a valid role for user
```

Comment: Can you checkout the workspace using command line?

Comment: No I don't have build manager rights for that server. I can't request for the same. I have developer rights. Is there any way we can change this?

Comment: I can check out the code using synergy software.

Comment: Ok. In that case, you cannot set the role yourself. By the way, are you the only person who will be accessing that particular Jenkins setup?

Comment: Yes, I will only be having the access.

Comment: Cool! Then are you able to checkout the code on that machine using command line?

Comment: Can you help me in verifying that ?

Comment: I don't remember the command. Worked on it long time back. Is this the first time you're working with Synergy? Are you able to checkout the project using Synergy GUI?

Comment: Get your admin to create a build user. Do you really want the nightly build with your user? My more serious answer is start an initiative to move away from that beast.

Comment: @user3783125: If you're able to checkout using Synergy GUI on the given box, then i guess it should not be a problem with Jenkins as well _as long as you are using the same credential in the plugin_. Give it a try.

Comment: If this is just for testing/POC, it's fine otherwise i agree with @JeffC's comment that you should ideally have a build user created for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up with @technext's cpmment

the synergy plugin actually runs something like this:

```
ccm start ... [options]
ccm set role build_mgr
ccm attr -s status -p $CCM_PROJECT
ccm attr -s maintain_wa -project $CCM_PROJECT
ccm attr -s wa_path -project $CCM_PROJECT
ccm attr -m wa_path -v $WORKSPACE -project $CCM_PROJECT
ccm update -r -keep_subprojects -p $CCM_PROJECT
ccm stop
```

the ccm attr require build_mgr, but I don't think update does. So skip the ccm attr by not using the plug-in.

What you can do is use the `ccm copy_project PROJECT,PREP...` to get your prep project and then run.

```
ccm update -r -p $CCM_PROJECT
```

IBM has some wonderful [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/synhelp/v7m2r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.synergy.manage.doc%2Ftopics%2Fsc_t_h_copy_project.html)